# Access Repository containing folders with jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, repository, nexus

I need some help with my project and would love to get it here.

What i want to do: compare JAR files. More precisely i want to access the .class files and have a look on the parameters of methods. This part is done so far.

My Problem: A big part of the JARs i want to compare lie on a Repo which is accessible through its url.
Is there a way in which i can access the URL and iterate through the folders in that repo getting to the JAR files?

I hope someone here can help me. Thank you very much

Best Regards,
Ronald Rempel

P.S.: It is a Nexus Repo. So maybe there is a more direct way to get to the folders and JARs in that Repo. Maybe an API for a Nexus Repo?

Answer (score 1):

What I could think of:

Method 1:
List all jars you want to compare as dependencies in a project.
Use Antrun, in antrun plugin  you can use maven dependency classpaths. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

From antrun call your java code and in that pass this as an argument. 
And then your code can lookup the jar, in them look at classes and their member details and do whatever diff you need.

Method 2:
Write a maven plugin, in that you can get a hold of your project deps and then resolve them to the local repository cache files and then run your code to diff them out.